# 'content' attribute to inherit node value

Tags: css, css-content

Is there a way to inherit node value into `content` attribute?

Like, if `<h2/>` tag value is set to "Random title", can I get this value inside `content` attribute in CSS?

I've tried `content: inherit;`, but it doesn't seem to work.

An example of my theory:

HTML:

```
<h2>Random title</h2>
```

CSS:

```css
h2:after {
    content: inherit; /* should be "Random title" */
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you just want to mirror the text, you can use something like `text-shadow: black 20em 0 0;`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, there's no way to do that. That's not what [`inherit` is for](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#value-def-inherit).

The closest you can get is this:

```
<h2 data-title="Random title">Random title</h2>

h2:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
}
```

..which is obviously horrible because of the duplication.

Comment: Note that if you're looking to "inherit" Unicode characters codes in this manner, you should be using the HTML character escape form of `&#x[code];`, for example `data-title="&#xe001;"`. This is useful when using font-based icons such as IcoMoon.

Comment: I think that's a brilliant idea, what so ever.

Comment: That's very useful!

Answer (score 10):

CSS3 has a way, `content: contents;` but (a) it seems to be contrived in such a way as to not be useful; and (b) probably isn't implemented anywhere yet. See http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-content/#contents0

@thirtydot's answer is correct for now, at least.

Comment: Can't wait until `content: contents;` is supported!

Comment: definitely need this feature!

Comment: 8 years later and still no `contents` support :/