# Can CSS access the content of an element as it can the attributes?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['content' attribute to inherit node value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175113/content-attribute-to-inherit-node-value)

I know you can access the content of an element's attribute like this:

```
a[href]:after { content: " (" attr(href) ")"; }
```

Is there a way to access the actual textual content of the element? What I need to do is make an `<h2>` on the page appear as if it's duplicated (for styling purposes) without actually having it duplicated in the markup.

I can't pull this off with a simple `text-shadow` because I need this duplicated version to appear behind an image while the original appears above.

Comment: why the restriction on the markup? I can't think of a reason that coud possibly require that no additional markup is added - after all it costs nothing. Curious to know why that's all.

Comment: It doesn't cost nothing. It costs a few extra characters.

Comment: My answer in the linked question might be good enough. Yes, the text is duplicated, but at least it's only in an attribute and not another element. I'm guessing you don't want to duplicate it for semantic reasons, or maybe "SEO purposes"?

Comment: Right. Semantically speaking, it's a bad idea to have duplicate content in the markup for the sole purpose of styling.

Comment: @thirtydot - If you put that as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0):

The following may help

```
E::first-line   the first formatted line of an E element
E::before           generated content before an E element
E::after            generated content after an E element
```

However I beleive what you want to do can be done by z-index and position:relative or position:absolute. Use js to duplicate the h2 tag and add a class to position it behind the image.