# Use content of an element in attr() of pseudo-element

Tags: css, html, pseudo-element, css-content

I have the following text:

```
<span class="page-number">42</span>
```

And I want to create a pseudo-element with something like this:

```css
span.page-number::after {
    content: attr(text());
}
```

Such that the content of the pseudo-element is the text of the  element, in this case 42. Can I do something like that through some trickery?

Comment: No, no you can't. You could, perhaps, emulate it (so long as 42 is the actual forty-second span, or an element within the forty-second something), with a CSS counter, but there's no way for CSS to take the 'text of an element,' unless that text is stored within a (ideally custom `data-*`) attribute

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175113/content-attribute-to-inherit-node-value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **data-*** attribute (i.e: `data-number`) and the CSS `attr()` getter function inside a `::before` or `::after` pseudo element:

```css
span::after {
  content: attr(data-number);
}
```

```html
<span class="page-number" data-number="Item No.42">42</span>
```

Comment: Well, one day when CSS is turing complete, we'll look back upon today as a better time.

Comment: [Named strings](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-content-3/#named-strings) in CSS3 Generated Content allows referencing the element content, but it's not supported anywhere.