# Children :before content inheritance

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-content

The title might be a little bit confusing but I wonder why is it impossible for a child element to inherit it's parent `::before` content. for example:

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="baz"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo::before {
    content: 'bar';
}

.foo .baz::before {
    content: inherit;
}
```

I have tried it that way, and even this way:

```
.foo > .baz::before {
    content: inherit;
}
```

and this one:

```
.foo::before ~ .baz::before {
    content: inherit;
}
```

...and none of the above worked... Is it possible at all? if not, which options do I have in order to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I think I might found a way to do such thing:

```
.foo {
    content: 'bar';
}

.foo > .baz,
.foo > .baz::before {
    content: inherit;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175113/content-attribute-to-inherit-node-value

Comment: @Michael Coker: That's different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['content' attribute to inherit node value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175113/content-attribute-to-inherit-node-value)

Comment: @EbrahimPoursadeqi as BoltClock said, that's different. I am aware to the `data-` attribute option - but that's not what i'm looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `::before`/`::after` pseudo-element cannot inherit from another `::before`/`::after` pseudo-element. A pseudo-element can only inherit from its originating element — this is the element that the pseudo-element is attached to. A pseudo-element cannot even inherit from the *parent* of its originating element, [unless the originating element itself is also inheriting from its parent and the property involved is not `content`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124953/can-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-inherit-height-from-the-parent-elemen/12124977#12124977).

In your example, `.foo::before` can only inherit from the `.foo` it's attached to, and likewise for `.baz::before` and `.baz`. `.baz::before` cannot inherit from `.foo::before`, so what you're trying to do is not possible. There does not appear to be a reliable way to ensure that one pseudo-element always inherits from another pseudo-element through CSS alone without enforcing this within the markup itself.

Comment: Well, I hope that maybe CSS4 will support such thing. It can be really useful and make my (and other people's) life easier. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You can also check the [content CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content) for a complete list of possible values.

Comment: @natanel97: This might be possible with css-content-3, but it only just resumed work after over 10 years of being abandoned so I can see why you alluded to CSS4 (which doesn't exist by the way, just self-contained level 4 CSS specs) ;)